# Why can't the Alpertron solve this Pell-like equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Dario Alpern's [*Alpertron*](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) is convenient for solving Pell and Pell-like equations.  It can even solve the one at the heart of [Archimedes' cattle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_cattle_problem),

$$p^2-(4)(609)(7766)(4657^2)q^2=1$$

and give its 100000-digit fundamental solution in about a minute (and that's using an old computer). However, while testing the Pell-like equation for various integer $n$,

$$x^2 - 3\big(108(3n^2)^6 - 1\big)y^2 = 3n^2\tag{1}$$

the Alpertron can solve for ***some***, but says that $n = 5$ (among others) has no solutions. But $(1)$ in fact has a parametric solution,

$$x,y = 486n^7, n$$

So why can it solve some $n$ of $(1)$, but not others? (There is a step-by-step button which may partly explain his algorithm.)

$\color{green}{Edit\, (Nov.\, 24)}$

As pointed out by Will Jagy in his answer below, the problem seems to be that $x,y$ of $(1)$ have a common factor. However, Alpertron also can't solve,

$$x^2-dy^2 = 32\tag{2}$$

for $d=761$ (co-prime $x,y = 469, 17$), $d=1489$ ($x,y = 39,1$), and many others. Thus while it is an excellent source, if it says "*No solutions*", let the user be aware that with its present code, *it can be mistaken*.

P.S. I've tried emailing Alpern about this bug, but he seems to be using an old [comment/guestbook](http://htmlgear.lycos.com/wgb/wgbview.dbm?owner=alpertron) which retired April 2012.

Comment: I blame the parents.

Comment: Does that title really mean what you want to ask? If a program "can't" "not" solve a problem, then it must solve the problem.

Comment: @Byron: Oops, there goes my English as a second language. I can't believe this question stood for 2 months without anyone pointing it out. I'll change it. :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Little things like that bug me. :)

Comment: You may want to also try [this Pell equation solver](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/main_pell.html), where the author gave a useful [reference](http://www.numbertheory.org/papers.html#jtnb) regarding the method.

Comment: Currently, Alpertron says: "Last updated on 18 January 2021". It now has no problem solving $x^2-671y^2=32$ or $x^2 - 57665039062497 y^2=75$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have answered on MSE many times about this: using Lagrange/Gauss method, you can find the cycle of "reduced" forms in the equivalence class of $x^2 - t y^2.$  Furthermore, the disciminant of this form being $4t,$ all primitively represented values with absolute value up to $$  \frac{1}{2} \sqrt {4t} = \sqrt t $$ is found as a first coefficient of one of the forms.

Perhaps the kicker is PRIMITIVE representations. For you, $\gcd(n,486 n^7) = n. $ I would say that any solution to your problem with $n=5$ must have both $x,y$ divisible by $5.$ That would throw off the usual method. I think you should expect the same trouble for $n=5,11,17,23,29,41,\ldots$

EDIT, 5 March 2014: I just noticed the trouble about 32 with d=761, 1489. Lagrange's method easily gives these, see below where 32 occurs as the first coefficient of one of the forms (triples).

```
  jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
761

0  form   1 54 -32   delta  -1
1  form   -32 10 23   delta  1
2  form   23 36 -19   delta  -2
3  form   -19 40 19   delta  2
4  form   19 36 -23   delta  -1
5  form   -23 10 32   delta  1
6  form   32 54 -1   delta  -54
7  form   -1 54 32   delta  1
8  form   32 10 -23   delta  -1
9  form   -23 36 19   delta  2
10  form   19 40 -19   delta  -2
11  form   -19 36 23   delta  1
12  form   23 10 -32   delta  -1
13  form   -32 54 1   delta  54
14  form   1 54 -32

 disc   3044
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-27201  -1484800
-46400  -2532801


 Pell automorph 
-1280001  -35310400
-46400  -1280001

Pell unit 
-1280001^2 - 761 * -46400^2 = 1 

=========================================

Pell NEGATIVE 
-800^2 - 761 * -29^2 = -1 

=========================================

761       761

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$



jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell
Input n for Pell 
1489

0  form   1 76 -45   delta  -1
1  form   -45 14 32   delta  1
2  form   32 50 -27   delta  -2
3  form   -27 58 24   delta  2
4  form   24 38 -47   delta  -1
5  form   -47 56 15   delta  4
6  form   15 64 -31   delta  -2
7  form   -31 60 19   delta  3
8  form   19 54 -40   delta  -1
9  form   -40 26 33   delta  1
10  form   33 40 -33   delta  -1
11  form   -33 26 40   delta  1
12  form   40 54 -19   delta  -3
13  form   -19 60 31   delta  2
14  form   31 64 -15   delta  -4
15  form   -15 56 47   delta  1
16  form   47 38 -24   delta  -2
17  form   -24 58 27   delta  2
18  form   27 50 -32   delta  -1
19  form   -32 14 45   delta  1
20  form   45 76 -1   delta  -76
21  form   -1 76 45   delta  1
22  form   45 14 -32   delta  -1
23  form   -32 50 27   delta  2
24  form   27 58 -24   delta  -2
25  form   -24 38 47   delta  1
26  form   47 56 -15   delta  -4
27  form   -15 64 31   delta  2
28  form   31 60 -19   delta  -3
29  form   -19 54 40   delta  1
30  form   40 26 -33   delta  -1
31  form   -33 40 33   delta  1
32  form   33 26 -40   delta  -1
33  form   -40 54 19   delta  3
34  form   19 60 -31   delta  -2
35  form   -31 64 15   delta  4
36  form   15 56 -47   delta  -1
37  form   -47 38 24   delta  2
38  form   24 58 -27   delta  -2
39  form   -27 50 32   delta  1
40  form   32 14 -45   delta  -1
41  form   -45 76 1   delta  76
42  form   1 76 -45

 disc   5956
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
-301402109537809  -23083652981172600
-512970066248280  -39287127144407089


 Pell automorph 
-19794264626972449  -763812428643688920
-512970066248280  -19794264626972449

Pell unit 
-19794264626972449^2 - 1489 * -512970066248280^2 = 1 

=========================================

Pell NEGATIVE 
99484332^2 - 1489 * 2578145^2 = -1 

=========================================

1489       1489

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

---

2016. I wrote a program that displays the x,y values. Looking at the cycle above, we se that all solutions of $x^2 - 761 y^2 = 32$ are images of these under the automorphism indicated.

      jagy@phobeusjunior:~$  ./Pell_Target_Fundamental

      1280001^2 - 761 46400^2 = 1

      x^2 - 761 y^2 = 32

      Sun May  8 08:21:00 PDT 2016

      x:  469  y:  17 ratio: 27.58823529411764  SEED 
      x:  43669  y:  1583 ratio: 27.58622867972204  SEED

      Sun May  8 08:22:00 PDT 2016

      x^2 - 761 y^2 = 32

      Pell automorph 
      1280001  35310400
      46400  1280001

      jagy@phobeusjunior:~$

Comment: Will, how can I finish off [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486792/how-to-prove-sum-k-1p-1-left-lfloor-frack3p-right-rfloor-fracp/486841#486841)?

Comment: Is the troublesome $n$ for primes $n = 3m-1$?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, yes. A bit less predictable for composite $n$ divisible by some of those primes. Also, odd primes, so $n=6m-1$